# Python csv to list TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python

I am trying to get my test.csv file that looks like this:
hr,mime,active
100,0.41,1
101,0.19,1
102,0.18,1
103,0.6,1
104,0.45,1
105,0.7,1
90,0.4,1
72.43,0.17,1
73,0.17,1
110,0.5,1
120,1,1
130,2,1
72.19,0.5,1
72.68,0.5,1

To look like this:

```
data = ((100, 0.4, 1), (101, 0.19, 1), (102, 0.18, 1), (103, 0.4, 1),
        (104, 0.4, 1), (105, 0.4, 1), (90, 0.4, 1), (72.43, 0.17, 1),
        (73, 0.17, 1), (110, 0.5, 1), (120, 0.17, 1), (130, 0.18, 1),
        (72.19, 0.5, 1), (72.68, 0.5, 1))
```

I've tried the following:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = map(tuple, reader)
```

But when it is printed it looks like this:

```
[('hr', 'mime', 'active'), ('100', '0.41', '1'), ('101', '0.19', '1'), ('102', '0.18', '1'), ('103', '0.6', '1'), ('104', '0.45', '1'), ('105', '0.7', '1'), ('90', '0.4', '1'), ('72.43', '0.17', '1'), ('73', '0.17', '1'), ('110', '0.5', '1'), ('120', '1', '1'), ('130', '2', '1'), ('72.19', '0.5', '1'), ('72.68', '0.5', '1')]
```

Also when I try to run some code with hr I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: [('100 0.41 1',),('101 0.19 1',),...... How you are getting elements inside of your tuple comma seperated ? As in your csv file it is seperated by space.

Comment: csv file is separated by commas, original example was with space to show example of csv.  updated example with commas

Comment: In your output you are not expecting ('hr', 'mime', 'active') tuple ?

Comment: Yes, I do not want the ('hr', 'mime', 'active') to show it should show as: ((100, 0.4, 1), (101, 0.19, 1), (102, 0.18, 1), (103, 0.4, 1), (104, 0.4, 1), (105, 0.4, 1), (90, 0.4, 1), (72.43, 0.17, 1), (73, 0.17, 1), (110, 0.5, 1), (120, 0.17, 1), (130, 0.18, 1), (72.19, 0.5, 1), (72.68, 0.5, 1))

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import csv

def convert(line):
    return tuple(map(float, line))

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = tuple(csv.reader(f))[1:]
    data = tuple(map(convert, reader))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it comes out as: (('100', '0.41', '1'), ('101', '0.19', '1'), ('102', '0.18', '1'), ('103', '0.6', '1'), ('104', '0.45', '1'), ('105', '0.7', '1'), ('90', '0.4', '1'), ('72.43', '0.17', '1'), ('73', '0.17', '1'), ('110', '0.5', '1'), ('120', '1', '1'), ('130', '2', '1'), ('72.19', '0.5', '1'), ('72.68', '0.5', '1'))  I do not want the apostrophe to show between the digits.  It should show as: ((100, 0.4, 1), (101, 0.19, 1), (102, 0.18, 1), (103, 0.4, 1), (104, 0.4, 1)...etc

Comment: Just edited. It doesn't do exactly what you want, since you want the floats not to show the .0.